# Summation of quantity over all integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

The notation $\lambda = (1^{m_1} 2^{m_2} 3^{m_3}) \vdash n$ means that $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$ with $m_1$ 1's, $m_2$ 2's and so on. For instance, the partition (3, 1, 1) of 5 can be written as $(1^2 3^1) \vdash 5$ and the partition (2, 2, 1) of 5 can be written as $(1^1 2^2) \vdash 5$.

The following identity appears on Page 10 of [Igor Pak's survey on Partition Bijections](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/papers/psurvey.pdf) as Problem (2.1.6). It is marked as being important to advance the understanding of the material.

> Prove bijectively the following summation formula:
>
> $$\sum_{\lambda = (1^{m_1} 2^{m_2} 3^{m_3}) \vdash n}{\frac{1}{1^{m_1} m_1 ! \; 2^{m_2} m_2 ! \; 3^{m_3} m_3 ! \cdots}} = 1$$

How can we show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partitions correspond to conjugacy classes in the symmetric group $S_n$. To choose a permutation in the conjugacy class whose permutations have $m_k$ cycles of length $k$, we can choose elements for the cycles in $\frac{n!}{\prod_kk!^{m_k}}$ ways, we can choose their order within the cycles in $\prod_k(k-1)!^{m_k}$ ways, and we have to correct for the fact that permuting cycles of equal length among themselves in $\prod_km_k!$ ways yields the same permutation. Overall, that leads to a count of

$$
n!\prod_k\frac{(k-1)!^{m_k}}{k!^{m_k}m_k!}=n!\prod_k\frac1{k^{m_k}m_k!}
$$

permutations in the conjugacy class. As there are $n!$ permutations in $S_n$ overall, summing over all partitions (and thus all conjugacy classes) and dividing by $n!$ yields your result.